# `zipWithIndex` or not: how much do we gain?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a `case class` for a certain purpose.

```
case class SamplePair(
  arrayOfNumbers: ArrayBuffer[Int]
)
```

Suppose I have `sequenceOfSamplePair` have a `Seq` of our basic `SamplePair`, and I want to add some ordered numbers to the `arrayOfNumbers` element of each element.

One way is doing this:

```
val ctr = new AtomicInteger(0)
sequenceOfSamplePair.foreach{ entry => 
   entry.arrayOfNumbers += ctr.getAndIncrement()
}
```

Another way is doing this, using `zipWithIndex`.

```
sequenceOfSamplePair.zipWithIndex.foreach {
      case (entry, ctr) =>
        entry.arrayOfNumbers += ctr
 }
```

What would be the reasons to prefer the implementation using `zipWithIndex`? Is it more "functional"?

Comment: You don't really want a case class with mutable components, do you?

Comment: Why do you want to use an `AtomicInteger`?

Answer (score 2):

As both of your approaches are not functional i'd go with the first implementation.
In the second approach you mix a functional construct with a imperative construct whereas you loose all gains you could get out of a functional solution.

Also using a mutable buffer in the case class goes not well with a mutable Buffer.

a more functional approach could look like

```
case class SamplePair(numbers: List[Int])

val extendedSequenceOfSamplePair = sequenceOfSamplePair.zipWithIndex.map {
  case ( sp@SamplePair(oldNumbers), idx) => sp.copy( numbers = idx :: oldNumbers)
}
```

Comment: ok the idx is now added at the beginning but (idx :: oldNumbers.reverse).reverse would fix this

Answer (score 2):

I've just done some profiling with these two methods. There's no clear winner. If the pattern matching in the `zipWithIndex` is replaced with direct references (`_1` and `_2`) then it's slightly faster but still not a clear winner.

If you however use streaming like the following:

```
Stream.range(0, sequenceOfSamplePair.length).map { i =>
  sequenceOfSamplePair(i) += i
}
```

then, it's about 6x faster. That's because it is really very simple, just go through the counter one by one, directly adding to the number. 6x is a lot faster, meaning it seems that `getAndIncrement` makes it very, very slow in relative terms.

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better to use `Iterator.range` instead of `Stream.range`, since you don't need the memoization of a Stream ?